# FadeIn content jumps on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a fadeOut of a full screen image. The problem is that when the wrapper fadeIn it's content (the image on the middle ) makes a jump of about 20px.

Any idea why is that happening?

This is my code:

```
    // Home FadeIn
    function home_timeout(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#intro-image').fadeOut(700);
            $('#wrapper').fadeIn(700);
        }, 2000);
    }
```

It happens the first time the page is loaded and not on cache.

I have already added a height to the wrapper and still it doesn't fix it:

```
body.home #wrapper {
   display: none;
   height: 777px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `display` set to `none`, use `opacity`:

```
body.home #wrapper {
   opacity:0;
   height: 777px;
}
```

And then use `fadeTo()` method:

```
function home_timeout(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#intro-image').fadeOut(700);
            $('#wrapper').fadeTo(700,1);
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Try and see...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add height to navigation list....

add
    ul
    {
        height:110px;
    }

I hope this will fix your problem..